# Properties of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eval, interpreter

Can I safely assume that in any implementation of JavaScript,

<del>1.) for any object generated by the `var obj = { ... };` construct, `obj[s]` is `undefined` for any string `s` unless `obj[s]` has been explicitly set by my own code?</del>

<del>2.)</del> if `typeof obj === 'object'` (and `obj` does not stem from some global, pre-defined variable or function in the global namespace), `Object.hasOwnProperty(obj, s)` is `false` for any string `s` except when I have set property `s` explicity before or, maybe, when `Array.isArray(obj)` is `true`?

In short: Can I assume that user-generated objects that are neither arrays nor of function type do not have pre-defined own properties?

Background: I need to write an interpreter for a very tiny subset of JavaScript that should safely execute user code. I would like to leverage on the optimization capabilities of the JavaScript engine. Hence I am planning to (1.) parse the user's code, (2.) re-write the AST such that (a) no global names can be accessed, (b) property access is restricted by a construct like `((typeof obj === 'object') && Object.hasOwnProperty(obj, s)) ? obj[s] : undefined`, (3.) `eval` the re-written code. For this to work, it is necessary for the `object`s not to have predefined properties like, e.g., `(function () {}).caller`, as otherwise the user could make my interpreter to execute arbitrary code or mess with the global objects of my environment in general.

Does, maybe, anybody know of a package where something like this has been done already? My requirements are not high: I need to execute user code, the user needs to work with numbers, strings, arrays, objects, and functions, and I need to exchange these things with the user code.

Edit: First assumption is wrong, see answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assume #1. `obj[s]` will access inherited properties, not just own properties.

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(obj["__proto__"] === undefined);
console.log(obj["toString"] === undefined);
```

I think #2 is a safe assumption. The whole point of `hasOwnProperty()` is to distinguish inherited properties from properties that were assigned explicitly in the object.

Comment: Yet can I assume #1 if I re-state it to "for any object generated by the `var obj = { ... };` construct, `Object.hasOwnProperty(obj, s) ? obj[s] : undefined` is `undefined` for any string `s` unless `obj[s]` has been explicitly set by my own code?